# Regex for obtain atmost 2 levels of a path

Tags: regex, parsing, re2

I have logs in the format:

```
"PUT /abc/def HTTP/1.1"
```

I need a pattern that can match 0,1,2 levels of the path from the log line in the above format.If the path has more than 2 levels only the first 2 levels should match
Eg: If the logs are like:

```
"PUT / HTTP/1.1"
"PUT /abc HTTP/1.1"
"PUT /abc/def HTTP/1.1"
"PUT /abc/def/egh HTTP/1.1"
```

The result i want extracted in a named group is:

```
/
/abc
/abc/def
/abc/def
```

Comment: `(?<=\s)\/(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?:\/[^\/ ]+){1,2}`  - either a `/` surrounded by whitepsace or whitespace followed by either 1 or 2 of "`/` followed by some text"   https://regex101.com/r/aughTI/1

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I want to extract the protocol as well along with the path .Something like (?P<request_path>(?<=\s)\/(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?:\/[^\/ ]+){1,2})| (?P<protocol>[^ ]*)"$
This works well when there are 0-2 levels.Can you help me with more than 2 levels. https://regex101.com/r/mrm19I/1

Comment: What about `^".*(?P<request_path>(?<=\s)\/(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?:\/[^\/ ]+){1,2}).* (?P<protocol>[^ ]*)"$`  https://regex101.com/r/xtqmXK/1

Answer (score 0):

Without verb;

```
(?<= )(\/[^\/\s]*){1,2}(?=.*HTTP.*)
```

With verb

```
(?<=").* (\/[^\/\s]*){1,2}(?=.*HTTP.*)
```

You can add a new capture if you need the HTTP as well...

Comment: Please check this out: https://regex101.com/r/69gIn6/1 . Unable to get desired output for "PUT /abc/def/egh HTTP/1.1"  Also the protocol can be anything not just HTTP.Thanks for helping

Comment: Hi, https://regex101.com/r/N2u6LN/1 this is the way I suggest. Is there anything missing in this one?

Comment: Hi,I want to capture the HTTP/1.1 part as well in a separate named group .But when I add a named group for that "PUT /abc/def/egh HTTP/1.1" mismatches as you can see here :https://regex101.com/r/69gIn6/1

Comment: Then you can use (?<= )((\/[^\/\s]*){1,2})(?:.*?) ([^\s]*)(?=\/) as in https://regex101.com/r/dATqnq/1

But you should use capture #1 as path and capture #3 as protocol